# Is there a way to multiply rows of columns and erase the duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with columns regarding sales.
There's a column called "UnitPrice", that has the price of each product
A column called "Product Key", that has a key number of each product
And lastly there is a column called " Sales Amount".
The problem here is that the sales amount is one at at time so the productkey and the unitprice are repetead
I want to do a data frame with the total sales amount of each product and multiply it by the price.

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(`Product Key`) %>%
    summarise(Sales_out = sum(UnitPrice * `Sales Amount`, na.rm = TRUE))
```